# awscli 1.18.34 has requirement botocore==1.15.34, but you'll have botocore 1.15.49 which is incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, tox, botocore

I am getting this error after upgrading to python version 3.7 from 2.7.

How to solve this error?

```
ERROR: tox 3.14.6 has requirement importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8", but you'll have importlib-metadata 4.6.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: awscli 1.18.34 has requirement botocore==1.15.34, but you'll have botocore 1.15.49 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it would be interesting how you installed the packages?

Did you install this e.g. from an old `requirements.txt`?

Looks like you have very old packages installed.

First, please install the latest version of `tox`, which is version `3.23.1`.

There is no longer a restriction of `importlib-metadata<2`.

Also, the latest version of `awscli` is `1.19.106`.

If there is no special reason why you want to use the old version, please install the current one.

Actually, I'd suggest to create a new virtual env, and install everything from scratch - without the version pinned to outdated versions.

If your repository is public, I could have a look and give more advice.

Comment: Hey its part of an old requirement.txt, can I update the old requirement.txt, add newer version and start from the scratch?

Comment: Well, in a `requirements.txt` there are usually both direct and transitive dependencies. I can't tell you how yours is generated. It could be that you only have e.g. `tox` and `awsclient` as direct dependencies, and all other listed packages depend on those two, and so your `requirements.txt` is maybe very long, and it would be tedious to update each package. I would start from scratch, install all the projects direct dependencies, and then do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate a new `requirements.txt`.

Comment: my requirements.txt is very small i mean there is just one dependency Django and Django realated dependecies